# Opposite of 'onFocus' in React

Tags: reactjs, onfocus

I have a scenario  where there has to be a event triggered when the input selected goes out of Focus.

There is already a onFocus event trigger when input is focused

```
<input onFocus={this.callFunction}/>
```

I need to know if there is an event that can be triggered when the selected input goes out of Focus. I could not find in React forms site

```
<input outOfFocus={this.callFunction}/>
```

Any Suggestion on this will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

There is event `onBlur`

```
<input onBlur={this.callFunction} />
```